# What kind of surface is it?

Tags: differential-geometry

How can we know which surface is one of the following:

- a quadric cone
- paraboloid of revolution
- hyperbolic cylinder

what should the surface satisfy at each case?

For example $r(u,v)=(u-v, u+v, u^2+v^2)$.

$$$$

Edit:

If we have the surface $r(u,v)=(\cosh u , \sinh u , v)$ then $x=\cosh u$, $y=\sinh u$, $z=v$. It stands $$x^2-y^2=1$$ and $$z=v$$ What can we do in that case where we cannot write one equation with $x$, $y$ and $z$ ?

Comment: Write $r(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$ ; we see that $x^2/2+y^2/2=z$, that is,  your manifold is an elliptic paraboloid : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric.

Comment: I understand! If we have the surface $r(u,v)=(\cosh u , \sinh u , v)$ then $x=\cosh u$, $y=\sinh u$, $z=v$. It stands $$x^2-y^2=1$$ and $$z=v$$ What can we do in that case where we cannot write one equation with $x$, $y$ and $z$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate $u,v$ between the given equations.

In the case of the example,

$$y+x=2u,\\
y-x=2v,\\
4z=(y+x)^2+(y-x)^2=2y^2+2x^2.$$

This is a paraboloid of revolution( in cylindrical coordinates, $4z=2r^2$.).

Comment: Why is this a paraboloid of revolution? Which is the general form of a paraboloid of revolution?

Comment: See the wikilink.

Comment: Ok! If we have the surface $r(u,v)=(\cosh u , \sinh u , v)$ then $x=\cosh u$, $y=\sinh u$, $z=v$. It stands $$x^2-y^2=1$$ and $$z=v$$ What can we do in that case where we cannot write one equation with $x$, $y$ and $z$ ?

Comment: That's a nice hyperbolic cylinder. Check the wikilink.

Comment: So we look only at $x^2-y^2=1$ and not at $z=v$. Correct?

Comment: Right, $z$ can take any value, irrespective of $x,y$.